# APT broken caused by package "libgl1-mesa-dri"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, apt

The command APT won't work at all due to having "unmet dependencies" related with libglx-mesa and libgl1-mesa-dri

```
root@pc /h/jose [100]# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not installable
 xorg : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried using commands such as apt --fix-broken install, apt install -f, dpkg --configure -a, and a lot of pages and posts, but nothing worked, I even disabled all my ppas just in case. APT won't perform any action because of this problem.

Comment: I had to reinstall Ubuntu. I could not find any fix to this problem online.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this command (mentioned the packages from `apt update` output that have been kept back):

```
sudo apt upgrade libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

and the upgrade has been successfully done